# Code prevention of sending bitcoin to an address on the wrong chain btc/bch/bsv

Tags: bitcoin-cash, cross-chain-recovery, address-format

Since they share several common addressing schemes, can I figure out in code how to send them to the right chain?

Answer (score 1):

There are three partial remedies:

- `bech32` addresses are invalid on BCH and BSV
- `CashAddr` is an alternative encoding (inspired by bech32) for `p2pkh` and `p2sh` addresses that is only valid on BCH and BSV
- You can check whether the recipient address is subject to address reuse: if it was previously used on another network, you should request confirmation or another address from the recipient

Unfortunately, BSV and BCH share all address formats, so you cannot distinguish which network an address was generated for between the two.

Likewise, the original `p2pkh` and `p2sh` addresses are valid on all three networks and there is no way to distinguish which network an address was intended for just from the address itself.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, they don’t support the same addressing schemes. They use a modified version of bech32 that is incompatible.

Comment: I believe all three can do P2PKH, P2SH, AND Bech32? No?